# Is there a reason to manually set an IP vs setting DHCP to assign a specific IP?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dd-wrt

I'm running on a DDWRT'd (Linksys) router. I want to have static IPs on a few of my machines for port forwarding and tracing. I'm wondering if there are any benefits to one method over the other -- manually setting a static IP in the adapter configuration settings, or setting up static DHCP leases inside DDWRT.

Any reasons/benefits for utilizing one way over another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One benefit is the option for **central management** with DHCP. You configure all your **reservations** in one place instead of logging onto every affected machine and setting a fixed IP there. It is also easier to keep it tidy that way.

Plus, the DHCP server can also give out various other data - most commonly **DNS servers** and **routes** for the network. Very convenient to only configure this at a single location.
Thanks for the second point: [Piskvor](https://superuser.com/users/2249/piskvor)

Comment: Plus, the DHCP server can also give out various other data - most commonly DNS servers and routes for the network. Very convenient to only configure this at a single location.